# C# dynamic fails invoking method from a base interface

Tags: c#, dynamic

Take the following code:

```
ICanQuack quack = new Duck();
var map = (object) "a map";
quack.Fly((dynamic)map);
```

using those types

```
public interface ICanFly
{
    void Fly<T>(T map);
}

public interface ICanQuack : ICanFly
{
    void Quack();
}

public class Duck : ICanQuack
{
    public void Fly<T>(T map)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Flying using a {0} map ({1})", typeof (T).Name, map);
    }

    public void Quack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quack Quack!");
    }
}
```

Compiled with C# 5 compiler against .NET 4.5.1 (the behaviour is probably the same using older compiler/framework version) this generates the following error:
[image]

Now, I have a pretty good idea **what** is happening under the covers (I blogged about it [here](http://kozmic.net/2013/11/27/on-c-dynamic-and-calling-base-types-methods/)) but I can't come up with a satisfying answer **why**?

Comment: I suspect the answer may be "bug" :) But I'll look in more detail later.

Comment: Interesting question! I guess `dynamic` cannot be used as type parameter for generics because it is not an actual type.

Comment: @Aschratt This is a nested interface issue. Check out his blog.

Comment: Based on Kyles answer, your question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696047/why-calling-isetdynamic-contains-compiles-but-throws-an-exception-at-runtim

Comment: I agree with gleng; `dynamic` doesn't appear to know of base interfaces according to that error message. Not sure if that's true for all cases tho (as I extreme-rarely use `dynamic`).

Comment: @JonSkeet  Just came across this exact issue with some code we are doing.  Are you aware if this is a bug as the link in the question is an 404 page. Thank you.

Comment: @dreza: Which link? I can only see one link in the question, and that works fine for me...

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, ok.  Thanks for responding.  I actually meant to say the link in the answer - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597276/dynamic-runtime-fails-to-find-iset-t-contains-during-runtime.  I guess maybe I don't have permissions.  Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am guessing this situation has already been reported to Microsoft.

Take a look [**here**](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597276/dynamic-runtime-fails-to-find-iset-t-contains-during-runtime)

Comment: yeah, looks like it is the case. I guess the fix didn't make the cut into .NET 4.5.1 and 2013 compiler either then.