# Can I access an explicitly implemented property using dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, duck-typing

I have the following usecase. There'a `ISpecificInterface` interface with `SpecificProperty` property that is explicitly implemented by `SpecificInterfaceImplementation` class. My code implements the callback that is passed `object` which refers to the `SpecificInterfaceImplementation` instance. The problem gets worse - there're several different versions of `ISpecificInterface` each having `SpecificProperty` with the same type (of the property) possible and my program needs to work with any of them and preferably without code duplication.

I'd use duck typing via C# `dynamic`:

```
dynamic theInterface = theObjectPassed;
String propertyValue = theInterface.SpecificProperty;
```

but since the property is explicitly implemented I get `RuntimeBinderException` with the following text

> 'SpecificNamespace.SpecificInterfaceImplementation' does not contain a definition for 'SpecificProperty'

and so I need to somehow get to the interface. I would not use a cast because the cast would expose a specific version of the interface and work only for that version and duck typing would be gone. So I use Reflection directly:

```
Type objectType = theObjectPassed.GetType();
var specificInterface = objectType.GetInterface("SpecificInterface");
var specificProperty = specificInterface.GetProperty("SpecificProperty");
var propertyValue = specificProperty.GetValue(specificInterface);
```

and it works just fine but it requires a ton of extra code.

Can I somehow use `dynamic`s and duck typing to avoid this ton of code with Reflection?

Comment: Ton of code? 4 lines? Come on...

Comment: @Alberto: Large difference compared to just `theInterface.SpecificProperty`.

Comment: Probably I'm doing something wrong, but it works perfectly on my machine as I would expect it. dynamic refers to _runtime_ type of instance it operates on, and if it can not find a field, that means that field actually does not exist in that type.

Comment: @Tigran: Sure and if the *runtime type* implements the property explicitly the property will be inaccessible.

Comment: @sharptooth: look here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/HacuWe. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Have an interface that all of the ISpecificInterface are based on with this property, then just cast to that?

Comment: @Tigran: Nope, something like this: http://dotnetfiddle.net/3OWv1e

Comment: @Joe: I cannot introduce a new interface - I'm just implementing teh callback. Whatever comes to that callback I should handle.

Comment: @sharptooth sounds like a poor design. I'd throw the reflection stuff you've already got into a method and use that. This isn't what `dynamic` was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use so much the `dynamic` feature of C#, but, from what I know and I see in your code, you should be able to access to the property `SpecificProperty` of `theInterface`, since it's declared explicitly.

My two cents: Using Reflection, the same task is achieved and I don't see a greater saving of lines of code (from 1 line to just 4 lines).

**EDIT**: With a little research, I found that your code is fine (I think it also compiles perfectly, because the dynamic reference is resolved at runtime) and this could be a bug in the `dynamic` feature, as explained in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696047/why-calling-isetdynamic-contains-compiles-but-throws-an-exception-at-runtim).