# Why is a RuntimeBinderException thrown when an inherited method is called on the interface type passing a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Can you please explain the behavior for this code:

```
namespace DynamicTesting
{
    public interface IDynamicTargetBase
    {
        string Hello(int a);
    }

    public interface IDynamicTarget : IDynamicTargetBase
    {
    }

    public class DynamicTarget : IDynamicTarget
    {
        public string Hello(int a)
        {
            return "Hello!";
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic a = 123;

            IDynamicTargetBase obj1 = new DynamicTarget();
            obj1.Hello(a);  // This works just fine

            IDynamicTarget obj2 = new DynamicTarget();
            obj2.Hello(a); // RuntimeBinderException "No overload for method 'Hello' takes '1' arguments"
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

> [Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: No overload for method 'Hello' takes '1' arguments]
>      at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IDynamicTarget , Object )
>      at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
>      at DynamicTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) :line 30

If I use `int` instead of `dynamic` then it's working fine.
I cannot get why it's not working. Do you have any ideas?

Try it on your own: https://dotnetfiddle.net/55ZMAG

Comment: Bizarre. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Interestingly, even when the argument type is changed to `dynamic` in the interface and the class, [the error still happens...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKqsHc)

Comment: looks like the CLR can't find the method because it's not declared on `IDynamicTarget`. If a method is declared on the base class it works fine.

Comment: Is this possibly a similar problem like in the following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071634/strange-behaviour-when-using-dynamic-types-as-method-parameters